# How do I get Shotwell to stretch small pictures to fill the screen in fullscreen mode?

Tags: 11.10, fullscreen, shotwell

If I have an image in Shotwell that is smaller than my screen's resolution, I would like it to be stretched to fill the screen when I am viewing images in fullscreen mode, like it is in Eye of GNOME and in damn near every other app with a fullscreen mode I've ever used. But there doesn't seem to be an option to do this in Shotwell.

Answer (score 1):

You appear to be correct - no automatic way to do this.  Perhaps contact the [developers for this option](http://www.yorba.org/) (contact page on their website)

The best you can do is to manually zoom in when in full-screen mode i.e.

[image]

[image]